# p:selectOneMenu keeps deselecting

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a bug, I have in a page, 3 `<p:selectOneMenu>`s and 1 `<p:selectManyMenu>`

They work in order, I select the first, it fills the second, the secon fill the third and the third fill s the `<p:selectManyMenu>`. When I start to Select the values in the `<p:selectManyMenu>`(holding the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> button) the third `<p:selectOneMenu>` deselects. Executing the function that fills the `<p:selectManyMenu>`.

Anyone have ever seen this?

I'have a lot of experience with java, but just started with JSF and PrimeFaces.

Thank you all in advance.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"  
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:form id="formPatch">
    <table border="">
        <tr>
            <td height="180p" valign="top">
                <p:panel header="Configurar diretórios para extrair Objetos do Patch" style="width: 500px; height: 170px">                                              
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">                                               
                            <p:outputLabel value="Arquivo: " styleClass="format_label"
                                             for="nomePatch" />
                            <p:inputText id="nomePatch" value="#{patchMB.patchBean.fileName}" styleClass="format_input" required="true"
                                requiredMessage="Favor preencher o campo nome do arquivo ex: confg.txt">                                                            

                            </p:inputText>                                          

                            <p:outputLabel value="Repositórios:" styleClass="format_label" for="dirRep" />

                            <p:selectOneMenu id="dirRep" value="#{patchMB.patchBean.directoryRepositorio}"
                                     style="width: 350px">                                                                                                                                                  
                                <p:message for="dirRep" />

                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue="Selecione" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{patchMB.directoryRepCli}" />                                                                    
                                <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{patchMB.carregaDirProdCli}" render="dirProdCli" />

                            </p:selectOneMenu>

                            <p:outputLabel value="Prod/Clientes: " for="dirProdCli" />

                            <p:selectOneMenu id="dirProdCli" value="#{patchMB.patchBean.directoryProdCli}"
                                     style="width: 350px">                                                                                                                                                  
                                <p:message for="dirGap" />

                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue="Selecione" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{patchMB.dirProdCli}" />

                                <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{patchMB.carregaDirObjetos}" render="dirObj" />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                            </p:selectOneMenu>

                            <p:outputLabel value="Dir objetos: " for="dirObj" />

                            <p:selectOneMenu id="dirObj" value="#{patchMB.patchBean.directoryObjetos}"
                                     style="width: 350px">                                                                                                                                                  
                                <p:message for="dirObj" />

                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue="Selecione" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{patchMB.dirObjetos}" />                                             

                                <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{patchMB.carregarFiles}" render="pickListArq" />
                                <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{patchMB.carregarSelectMany}" render="objSelectMany" />                                                                   

                            </p:selectOneMenu>

                        </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>      
            </td>
            <td>
                <p:panel header="Escolha os arquivos para criação do patch" style="width: 500px">
                    <p:tab id="pickListTab" title="Transformadores">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                            <p:pickList id="pickListArq" value="#{patchMB.objetos}" var="pickListObj"
                                        itemLabel="#{pickListObj}" itemValue="#{pickListObj}">

                                        <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Selecione os objetos</f:facet>
                                        <f:facet name="targetCaption">Objetos do Patch</f:facet>                                                                                    
                            </p:pickList>                           
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:tab>
                </p:panel>

            </td>               
        </tr>           
    </table>
    </h:form>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: You'll need to post at least your page code, for anyone to see what's going on.

Comment: Here's the code for the SelectOneMenu: